# How to advertise my work to N+3 when N+1 and N+2 are the ones blocking my career?

Tags: politics

I've an N+1 and N+2 who are more a sale for all the projects I've done. They take advantage the fact I'm a shy engineer/scientist that they advocate my projects. But the fact is I've never have a chance to present my work in the meeting with N+3 despite I'm the one behind most of the work.

I'm faced with a problem that it seems no reason for me to cc my N+3 when I'm communicating work with N+1 and N+2. Since N+3 is very senior in ranks, it seems no way I can actually reach him on my own. And N+2 and N+1 is not every keen of connecting me to him as well. What they do is just to deprive me of every opportunities I could make the presentation of my own, in the name of sponsoring the project, or resorting to the same old excuse that I'm shy.

As a engineer, it's professionally demotivating. Suggestions have it like self-proposaling some project-sharing sessions to advocate for myself, however, I'm pretty sure N+3 would never attend due to his 'business'. And even if my N+2 or N+1 managed to attend, they would just take what I said to the next meeting where N+3 would be there.

Thus, as a result, it seems impossible for me to promote my own work when all the N+x just want to do it themselves. I feel my growth in the company is very limited in the long run as I would forever be used as a silent tool to accomplish whatever I'm thrown to do.

What are the things I can do within this company? I want career growth. Life is too short for making someone else look good instead of fighting my own battle up. And again, it's very demotivating as an employee.

p.s. the reason I wish to inform N+3 is apparent: my N+1 or 2 is apparently not concerning my career growth as long as they can take advantage of me. And informing N+3 would be the only resort I have for my career progression. However, I'm open to other suggestions as well. Thanks in advance!

p.s. thanks for the comments, I hereby address some of the concerns as follows.

> Updates 1: Some confusions about why I can't just direct advertise to N+3 is that I'm still junior with 3+ years experience only. And apparently N+1 and +2 only advocate the project in a way that benefits themselves without mentioning me. This confuses me.

> Update 2: I think my N+1 is two ranks senior than I. Thus, promoting me won't threat anyone in the hierarchy. And this confuses me why they want to hold me back.

Comment: What "career growth" are you after? What is the "ladder" in your company you want to climb? Are you looking to replace N+1, or are there different paths you have in mind?

Comment: I'm confused on why you think you should be able to present your work to N+3? I think you need more detail in your question, because the thought that you should be able to do this means I am missing some element of your job.

Comment: For all the concerns, I've hereby updated the post to address it.

Comment: It seems from your question and updates that you are craving recognition, and you are thinking the lack of recognition is some sort of conspiracy to keep you down. More likely that nobody actually cares about recognition. In the real world, there are problems that need solving, and provided they get solved, nobody really cares where the ideas come from.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, recognition to me is useless if it doesn't bring me promotion or salary increase.

Comment: @Student You're not going to get a promotion or salary increase for every thing you do. You're going to need a sustained level of performance. If you think you can do nothing for an entire year, and have one good idea to present to N+3 in order to get promoted, I fear you are going to be disappointed.

Comment: Normally, most workers won't even be able to reach their N+2 to advocate for their own career growth.  I am not making this up. This is the realistic scenario in any companies. Your best strategy is to follow user **Joe Strazzere**'s comment above: "**Either work to win over your boss (who is N+1), or find a new job**."

Answer (score 2):

> I've an N+1 and N+2 who are more a sale for all the projects I've
> done. They take advantage the fact I'm a shy engineer/scientist that
> they advocate my projects. But the fact is I've never have a chance to
> present my work in the meeting with N+3 despite I'm the one behind
> most of the work.

In my experience, advocating projects with your N+3 is incredibly rare. Typically things would get filtered/refined by both the N+1 and N+2, who have more experience, and often have more ability to present in a manner that is palatable to those higher up.

> I'm faced with a problem that it seems no reason for me to cc my N+3
> when I'm communicating work with N+1 and N+2. Since N+3 is very senior
> in ranks, it seems no way I can actually reach him on my own. And N+2
> and N+1 is not every keen of connecting me to him as well. What they
> do is just to deprive me of every opportunities I could make the
> presentation of my own, in the name of sponsoring the project, or
> resorting to the same old excuse that I'm shy.

Well yes, if you're poor at presenting (or shy as they call it), you are going to get your idea not only dismissed, but also you'll make it rather difficult to have their mind changed in the future. Far better to be presented to those that are more effective communicators.

> What are the things I can do within this company? I want career
> growth. Life is too short for making someone else look good instead of
> fighting my own battle up. And again, it's very demotivating as an
> employee.

I don't understand why you think you're making someone else look good. Are N+1/N+2 saying the idea was theirs?

> p.s. the reason I wish to inform N+3 is apparent: my N+1 or 2 is
> apparently not concerning my career growth as long as they can take
> advantage of me. And informing N+3 would be the only resort I have for
> my career progression. However, I'm open to other suggestions as well.
> Thanks in advance!

It's unclear what you mean by "can take advantage of me" means.

It seems like you don't think N+1 and N+2 will appreciate your work. That is a problem.

You should ask for an internal transfer into a position where you work will be valued by your seniors, who are prepared to advocate on your behalf.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Replies to the questions raised: i) i've demonstrated I actually can present (when the topic is so deep that only I can present), but still they are calling me shy and preventing me from as many presentations as possible really frustrates me. And I'm not sure how to do regarding this point.

Comment: Second, they usually ask for my opinion and then present without crediting me. Despite they don't explicitly say it's theirs, but their action makes no difference, I guess? What should I do?

Comment: @Student You should do your job.

Answer (score 1):

There is conjecture and unmet assumptions buried in your question.

Right off the bat, rarely does career growth happen like in the movies where someone pulls off an amazing project save, the CEO hears of it directly, invites you to their crib, and give you an exec team position. N+3 is going to be concerned that projects are met and almost never dabble with details 4 or 5 levels below them.

Career advancement instead is consistent growth and incremental promotion. So your boss, what plan does he/she/? have in place for your next promotion? Do you have reachable goals put in place before you are recommended for that promotion?

Promotions in my experience in software take place every 3-5 years for performing developers. Perhaps you are due for consideration? Take it up with your manager at your next 1:1, Express your desire and ask what you should focus on. Keep doing this, you will see growth.

Answer (score -6):

You put your big boy/big girl pants on, then you Cc in the big boss.

Find whatever justification you like:

- "I think this will improve productivity"
- "This idea could decrease costs and increase profitability"
- "I've had this idea and think it's cool, what do you think?"

Or, you find a reason to bump into them at work and you talk about the new and exciting things you are working on.

Your biggest issue is that you are second guessing yourself and putting up artificial barriers to yourself by thinking you are insignificant and unimportant.

You are not.

You are a skilled professional who does cool, interesting and exciting work, that your seniors ought to know about.

Comment: This is somewhat bad advice. This kind of behaviour is generally frowned upon and will more often end making ennemies more than supporters. You can climb the ladder, rarely jump rungs, or with the risk of slipping and falling. You recommend to shake the tree without knowing what will fall from it. Watch your head.

Comment: Maybe it's that NZ is a little more chill - but suffice to say, I've done this multiple times. If there's something important enough you think the big boss needs to know about - then you CC them in. Don't get me wrong, I'm not CC'ing in the big boss for every little thing - but probably will CC him on an issue about once a month.

Comment: Well, you can't/shouldn't skip levels like that. There's a chain of command, like any organisation/army and you have to respect it. I'm the boss, I don't want to be overloaded by emails that should be handled by the manager/head of dept.

Comment: @TheDemonLord This isn't about something being important, this is about the OP wanting to be as visible as possible to their bosses bosses boss.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie - Exactly - and the way I've become visible, is by making myself visible. If you think you are miniscule and unimportant, you will manifest that. If you think (within reason) you are important and someone ought to listen to what you have to say, you'll manifest that too. It's worked for me in my career and continues to work.